# Is there emacs plugins to do Sublime-like completion and goto anything?

Tags: emacs, sublime-text-2

In Sublime Text 2, I can enter `prnfunc[tab]` and then it completes to 'PrintFunction'. If I have a project, I can press `Cmd+P` and enter `srcpy/hello.py` and then it navigates to `source/python/hello_world.py`. Is there equivalents in emacs?

p.s. I think ido in emacs is provides similar fuzzy completion but only in mini-buffer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For completion, try [auto-complete](http://auto-complete.org/).  To get intelligent completion, you may need "backend" for each programming language.  For Python, try [Emacs-jedi](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/) (disclaimer: my project).  Auto-complete supports case-insensitive completion.

For project management, I recommend combination of [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) and [eproject](https://github.com/jrockway/eproject).  With these two, you can find `source/python/hello_world.py` by something like `s rc py hello RET`.  Helm is a framework for incremental completion and selection narrowing.  So you can get not only project management but also other features.  eproject is a project management plugin and it can act as backend of Helm.

Setting up everything at once could be tough work so I suggest to just setup plain auto-complete and Helm first.  Those two will give you a big improvement on your Emacs environment.

Answer (score 1):

For autocomplete, I use a modified version of emacs' `dabbrev-expand`. Here are the relevant sections of my `.emacs` file ([source](http://emacsblog.org/2007/03/12/tab-completion-everywhere/)):

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Make TAB expand words. Source:                             ;;
;; http://emacsblog.org/2007/03/12/tab-completion-everywhere/ ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(defun my-tab-fix ()
  (local-set-key [tab] 'indent-or-expand))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook          'my-tab-fix)
(add-hook 'cperl-mode-hook          'my-tab-fix)
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook          'my-tab-fix)
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook          'my-tab-fix)
(add-hook 'python-mode          'my-tab-fix)
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook         'my-tab-fix)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'my-tab-fix)
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Define the indent-or-expand function we ;;
;; just mapped to TAB                      ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(defun indent-or-expand (arg)
  "Either indent according to mode, or expand the word preceding
point."
  (interactive "*P")
  (if (and
       (or (bobp) (= ?w (char-syntax (char-before))))
       (or (eobp) (not (= ?w (char-syntax (char-after))))))
      (dabbrev-expand arg)
    (indent-according-to-mode)))
```

You may also be interested in [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) and [hippie expand](http://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/packages/html/edit-utils_23.html).

As for locating variable/function declarations, I use [Emacs Tags](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags). This is how I've set it up in my `~/.emacs` (not written by me, I found these lines somewhere or other):

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;                  ETAGS                 ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
  (defun create-tags (dir-name)
     "Create tags file."
     (interactive "DDirectory: ")
     (eshell-command 
      (format "find %s -type f -name \"*.[ch]\" | etags -L -" dir-name)))
  ;;;  Jonas.Jarnestrom<at>ki.ericsson.se A smarter
  ;;;  find-tag that automagically reruns etags when it cant find a
  ;;;  requested item and then makes a new try to locate it.     
  ;;;  Fri Mar 15 09:52:14 2002    

  (defadvice find-tag (around refresh-etags activate)
   "Rerun etags and reload tags if tag not found and redo find-tag.
   If buffer is modified, ask about save before running etags."
  (let ((extension (file-name-extension (buffer-file-name))))
    (condition-case err
    ad-do-it
      (error (and (buffer-modified-p)
          (not (ding))
          (y-or-n-p "Buffer is modified, save it? ")
          (save-buffer))
         (er-refresh-etags extension)
         ad-do-it))))

  (defun er-refresh-etags (&optional extension)
  "Run etags on all peer files in current dir and reload them silently."
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (format "etags *.%s" (or extension "el")))
  (let ((tags-revert-without-query t))  ; don't query, revert silently
    (visit-tags-table default-directory nil)))


(global-set-key "\M-s" 'tags-search)
```

Finally I also highly recommend the great [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) for anyone writing code on `emacs`:

> ECB stands for "Emacs Code Browser". While Emacs already has good
>   editing support for many modes, its browsing support is somewhat
>   lacking. That's where ECB comes in: it displays a number of
>   informational windows that allow for easy source code navigation and
>   overview.
>
> The informational windows can contain:
>
> - A directory tree,
> - a list of source files in the current directory (with full support and display of the VC-state),
> - a list of functions/classes/methods/... in the current file, (ECB uses the CEDET-semantic, or Imenu, or etags, for getting this list so all languages supported by any of these tools are automatically supported by ECB too)
> - a history of recently visited files (groupable by several criteria),
> - a direct and auto-updated ecb-window for the semantic-analyzer for some intellisense the Speedbar and
> - output from compilation (the compilation window) and other modes like help, grep etc. or whatever a user defines to be displayed in this window.